# How to keep Android tests running even if the cable is disconnected?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to run Android tests for my App even if the cable is disconnected from machine.

Scenario:

- I start Android tests from Android studio.
- The tests take long time to finish.
- The cable sometimes get disconnected (for many reasons) then the tests break.
- I have to reset test data
- Repeat from the beginning

However, I want my tests to keep running until they finish all test cases regardless of being connected to Android Studio.

Comment: Set up `adb` over WiFi: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Comment: @CommonsWare I am aware of adb over WiFi. However I am looking for disconnecting adb after running tests to keep them run without adb connection.

Comment: But... your question is focused on the cable being disconnected. With `adb` over WiFi, you unplug your cable before the tests begin. And, if you do not have an `adb` connection, what is the point of running the tests? How are you planning on getting test results?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the question is more about running tests on physical device. If that's the case, you may want to consider adb over tcp: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless however you will end up with another problem: your device will need to be charged from time to time, which basically means plugging your device anyways. Thus I'd suggest using Firebase test lab if that's an option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab. Last time I was checking, there was free tier for that.

Comment: I am aware of adb over WiFi. However I am looking for disconnecting adb after running tests to keep them run without adb connection.